# Re-doing a tfs checkin

Tags: tfs

Suppose you realized that you forgot to checkin just one file during a tfs checkin.

Is there a way to rollback the checkin, have the changes that were part of it show up as pending changes and just add the incremental file change. And then just check everything back in.

The reason for my weird request is as follows.

Suppose you do two separate checkins. But those checkins are not successive checkins in the folder/solutions history.

Then when i need to merge just my changes to parent branches, I need to do separate merges for each checkin in the child branch.

Annoyingly tfs doesnt allow non-contiguous checkin. And if the parents branches are gated ie they build each time after checkin, it can mean a wait time of 10 minutes per changeset/checkin. Aarghhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Rollback the original changeset
2. Checkin
3. Rollback the rollback
4. Add in the change you forgot the first time
5. Checkin

Comment: That is a sweet solution. Took me 15 seconds to get it. You are accepted and upvoted my friend.